# Executing a function once the page is fully loaded in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function-call, angularjs-1.6

I would like to execute this function as soon as the page is fully loaded.

```
vm.pointInvoice = () => {   
    if ($stateParams.property == "INVOICE") {
        vm.invoiceEdit($stateParams.checkin)
        vm.invoiceFocus = true;
        vm.receiptFocus = false;
    }
}
```

If I put the function as a button (just to test it), everything works perfectly

```
<button ng-click="vm.pointInvoice()">OPEN AND POINT TO INVOICE</button>
```

But, no matter what I do - I simply cannot get this to execute my function automatically (when the page is fully loaded and all data/elements are available).

Lucky me Stack Overflow had a lot of posts about page fully loaded so I tried a whole bunch of them but none of them works, they all fire off the function while the page is still blank.

These are some of the ones I have tried:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
    debugger;
});

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
});

$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
    debugger;
});
```

So my only idea left is to do some ugly `setTimeout(function(){ vm.pointInvoice() }, 3000);` hack but to me thats a bit like giving up :-D

There MUST be some way to fire off an function when the page is fully loaded....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to use the [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) directive:

```
<div ng-init="init()">...</div>
```

Define this function is your controller:

```
$scope.init = function() {
    alert("Page is fully loaded!);
}
```

---

*Anyway, you can call this function directly from your controller. It will be call once the app and the controller are loaded.*

Comment: Im gonna give it a try

Comment: I added it to the table where I needed the function to go and do stuff - and IT WORKED!!!  Thank you so much @Mistralis!!  
`<table class="book-table book-table-gray" ng-if="vm.invoiceRecord[0]._id" ng-cloak="" ng-init="vm.pointInvoice()">`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the right `angular` event?

**Angular < 1.6.X**

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    alert('page loading finshed');
});
```

**Angular >= 1.6.X**

```
angular.element(function () {
    alert('page loading finshed');
});
```

Comment: Yes tried that already, but fires when the page is still blank (for some reason)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something outside Angular JS?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /*code*/ }); //with jQuery

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ /*code*/ });
```